# What does "as" mean in this sentence?

Tags: meaning

> They add value as a systems integrator.

Does this sentence mean:

> As a systems integrator, they add value.

or

> They add value. This value is about systems integrator.

Comment: You are right that the sentence is formally ambiguous - the phrase _as a systems integrator_ could attach to the NP _value_ or to the whole predication. In practice, I think any native English speaker would understand it as attaching to the predication unless there was a strong context implying otherwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> They add value as a systems integrator.

There is ***as*** is a preposition and it is used to refer to the function or character that someone or something has.

So therefore you can say:

> They add value in the role of a systems integrator.